# Temporal convolution for NLP

Tags: nlp, neural-network, backpropagation, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to follow Kalchbrenner et al. 2014 (http://nal.co/papers/Kalchbrenner_DCNN_ACL14) (and basically most of the papers in the last 2 years which applied CNNs to NLP tasks) and implement the CNN model they describe. Unfortunately, although getting the forward pass right, it seems like I have a problem with the gradients.

What I'm doing is a full convolution of the input with W per row, per kernel, per input in the forward pass (not rotated, so it's actually a correlation).
Then, for the gradients wrt W, a valid convolution of the inputs with the previous delta per row, per kernel, per input (again, not rotated).
And finally, for the gradients wrt x, another valid convolution of the pervious delta with W, again, per row, per kernel, per input (no rotation).

This returns the correct size and dimensionality but the gradient checking is really off when connecting layers. When testing a single conv layer the results are correct, when connecting 2 conv layers - also correct, but then, when adding MLP, Pooling, etc. it starts looking bad. All other types of layers were also tested separately and they are also correct, thus, I'd assume the problem starts with the calculation of the grad. wrt W_conv.

Does anyone have an idea or a useful link to a similar implementation?

Comment: I'm working on an implementation in Torch 7.  If it helps, Kalchenbrenner posted Matlab code for this network on his website:  http://nal.co/DCNN